# RequestContentLengthMismatchError error when using jest for testing react native fetch apis

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, expo

I have a expo app and inside it some simple CRUD operations. App is works fine but when I want to write some test scenarios using jest, I get this error :

```
 FAIL  apis/index.test.tsx
 Fetching Tests
× Should return correct user name (1561 ms)

● Fetching Tests › Should return correct user name

TypeError: fetch failed



Cause:
RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header



Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.033 s
Ran all test suites.
```

and this is my code for testing :

```
describe("Fetching Tests", () => {
  it("Should return correct user name", () => {
    return SimpleCrudPersistence.addUser("ali", 12, "antalia").then((data) =>
      expect(data.name).toBe("ali")
    );
  }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I'm getting the same thing